# Automatic script which runs after open terminal

Tags: linux, scripting

I made a script which is run always when open the terminal. Anyone know how to detect that script? I forgot a path to directory which I put it

Comment: Your question title bears no relation to your question text :-)

Comment: Try the `find` command. It's named after its purpose. ;)  Start with `man find` to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF a particular user logged in then you want to execute script

Include script in below mentioned path

```
/home/user/.bashrc file
```

IF You want to execute the script at every reboot

Include the script in below mentioned path

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux bash will run the `~/.bashrc` script.

But in most cases, you want to add a line to your `~/.profile` script.

bash also has a logout script: `~/.bash_logout`

You should call your script from one of those. Say you put your script in `~/bin/my-script.sh`, then you could add:

```
~/bin/myscript.sh
```

at the end of `~/.profile`.

Note that if your script generates an error, you should see it next time you start your console. Under X-Windows, opening a new X-term console will run your script again, so you can test by closing and reopening the console.